# user_required decorator to authenticate user and company and branch by default

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, handler, middleware, webapp2

Each Branch of each company gets their own dashboard.
A user visits the dashboard for their branch (but is redirected to `/dashboard/<company>/<branch>/login` if they aren't logged in).

This means I will have very many handlers containing `<company>/<branch>` e.g:

```
_auth_routes = [
    RedirectRoute('/dashboard/<company>/<branch>/signup', SignupHandler, name="user-signup", strict_slash=True),
    RedirectRoute('/dashboard/<company>/<branch>/<type:v|p>/<user_id:\d+>-<signup_token:.+>',
                  handler=VerificationHandler, name='verification', strict_slash=True),
    RedirectRoute('/dashboard/<company>/<branch>/password', SetPasswordHandler),
    RedirectRoute('/dashboard/<company>/<branch>/login', LoginHandler, name='login'),
    RedirectRoute('/dashboard/<company>/<branch>/logout', LogoutHandler, name='logout'),
    RedirectRoute('/dashboard/<company>/<branch>/forgot', ForgotPasswordHandler, name='forgot'),
    RedirectRoute('/dashboard/<company>/<branch>/authenticated', AuthenticatedHandler, name='authenticated')
]
```

Each handler then needs get(company, branch, ..) and post(company, branch, ..)

Also most of the methods need decorating with the following decorator.

```
def user_and_company_and_branch_required(handler):
    def check_company(self, company, branch, *args, **kwargs):
        auth = self.auth
        if not auth.get_user_by_session():
            self.redirect(self.uri_for('login', company=company,
                                               branch=branch), abort=True)
        elif company != self.user_info['company_name']:
            self.redirect(self.uri_for('login', company=company,
                                        branch=branch), abort=True)
        elif branch != self.user_info['branch_name']:
            self.redirect(self.uri_for('login', company=company,
                                        branch=branch), abort=True)
        else:
            return handler(self, company, *args, **kwargs)

    return check_company
```

Finally every time I use self.uri_for I need to add the company & branch.

I'm wanting to abstract the company and branch so that I don't have to type it everywhere.

I'm considering making a second basehandler:

```
class BaseHandler2(BaseHandler):
    def get(self,company, branch):
        #sget meaning secure_get
        sget = user_and_company_and_branch_required(self.sget)
        sget(self)
    def post(self,company, branch):
        spost = user_and_company_and_branch_required(self.spost)
        spost(self)
```

usage:

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler2):
     def get():
         self.render_template("login_form.html")

class SecureDashboardHanlder(BaseHandler2):
     def sget():
         self.render_template("this is the secure page
                               for your company & username &branch")
```

**Would this be the recommended architecture for such a problem?**

Other options could be to use app.yaml regex somehow, or Custom Router class?

Note the user has a company_name and branch_name under user_attributes:

```
config = {
    'webapp2_extras.auth': {
        'user_model': 'dashboard_auth_models.User',
        'user_attributes': ['name', 'company_name']
    },
    'webapp2_extras.sessions': {
        'secret_key': 'f02fajgt9a309ga30gfbnxz252mn3b459082'
    }
}
```

**or perhaps it would be better just to use the decorator everywhere? and include company, branch in the arguments to every handlers get and post methods**

Comment: Oh and I didn't include a fix for self.uri_for requiring company & branch to be added as keywords. It would be bad practice to patch it right?

Comment: Unless a user needs to be able to access multiple dashboards why even have the paths to each dashboard expressed as URLs?  You aren't using URL traversal, so you aren't leveraging this for scoped permissions. If a user can only access a single dashboard, then which company branch they can access is a basic property of the user, and therefore you only need one set of dashboard URL's. THis also means people can't fiddle with URLs to get to other branches which they can in your model, then you have to secure/check each URL against the user.  

If they do  access multiple branches ignore me ;-)

Comment: Someone higher up in the company can access multiple branches of that company.
The main reason is from a user experience perspective. When an employee signs up, they signup at that companies dashboard rather than at a generic dashboard for all companies where they would select what company they work for.
The intention is to ensure only people Authorized by a branch can access a branch's dashboard. (hence the user_required decorator will check company and branch from user_info which the user can't edit).

Comment: But I'm now starting to reconsider doing what you said instead.. heh

Comment: Perhaps the first branch Manager (who is assigned by the company admin) can create "signup links", they send a "signup link" to the employee and that employee signs up. Although I prefer the idea of an employee signing up and then being "accepted" by an existing branch admin.

Comment: Okay I've figured out what to do. An Employee will create an account and then request verification by entering the branch admins username or email.

Comment: Should I delete this question or leave it for others?